# Built-in way to format a number with a space after the sign

Tags: php, format

Is there a built-in way to format a number with a space between the sign and the number?

Format with sign: `sprintf("%+0.2f", $number);`

What I'm looking for, not necessarily with sprintf (*not working*): `sprintf("%+ 0.2f", $number);`

Comment: Not necessarily the best solution, but this gets things done: `str_replace('+', '+ ', sprintf("%+0.2f", $number))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not think it is supported as it might be just not up to some ISO. I think, when you add extra space after sign, semantically it is not part of number anymore(do not quote me on that).

But to fix it:

```
<?php

$n = str_replace(
    ['-', '+'],
    ['- ', '+ '],
    sprintf("%+0.2f", $number)
);
```